# How to open exFAT SSD in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, exfat

I have some files on my SSD and I want to put them on my Ubuntu 12.04(64bit) desktop , but Ubuntu cannot open the exFAT SSD when I connect it via USB. How can I make it work?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14838/is-there-a-simple-way-to-add-exfat-support

Answer (score 40, accepted):

exFAT is a proprietary file system developed by Microsoft, and implementing it requires accepting a very restrictive license from Microsoft. However, there is a FUSE [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/exfat/) of exFAT for linux.

Since you are on a Ubuntu system, you can install the above-mentioned exFAT implementation from their [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~relan/+archive/exfat).

1. Add the PPA to your sources list by running

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:relan/exfat
   ```

   in your favourite terminal emulator
2. Install the `fuse-exfat` and the `exfat-utils` packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat exfat-utils
   ```

Now you should be able to use the SSD

Comment: This worked quite well for me.  Didn't even have to reboot.  Though for some reason it wouldn't install directly, so I just did a `sudo apt-get -d download fuse-exfat` followed by `sudo dpkg -i path/to/file.deb` ftw.

Comment: Worked like a charm with my 12.04 using these commands but within a sudo shell (sudo -s) instead of "sudo .." for each commands.

Comment: Worked for me in 12.04 as described. No need to "sudo -s".

Comment: Same for me, no need for `sudo -s`

Comment: What I meant by "sudo -s" was, opening a sudo shell and execute all the commands within it, instead of multiple "sudo ..&& sudo..".
I did not *need* to do this, I just did.

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:relan/exfat does not work at all

Comment: Still does not work, as of 18.04. Use the apt-get instructions from Amelia Torres, below.

Answer (score 16):

To install exfat on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander, you don’t need to add any extra PPA to your sources list. You only need to install the exfat-utils package.

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install exfat-utils
```

Ubuntu and Linux Mint will not automatically mount exFAT devices. 
To mount your exFAT device, plug in your device and run:

```
$ su -
# cat /proc/partitions
# cd /media
# mkdir usbdrive
# mount -t exfat /dev/sdd1 usbdrive
```

From [How to enable exFAT on Ubuntu](https://web.archive.org/web/20150306051159/http://www.namhuy.net/872/how-to-enable-exfat-on-ubuntu.html) (on Nam Huy Linux),
with a typo corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for mounting SSD or SD Card:
If you need to add the PPA to your sources then type following command in terminal,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:relan/exfat
```

Next you need to install the `exfat-utils` through following command,

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils
```

This will install both

> exfat-utils and exfat-fuse.

Then try to mount the SD Card or SSD. Hope this will work.

Note: while executing the second command for installing the `exfat-utils`, you may encounter the following issue:

> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
>   E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

This is because that only one program can hold the lock. Make sure that you are not running aptitude, synaptic or adept etc. To work around this issue, you just need to restart the machine and then opening the terminal and install the `exfat-utils` before doing or opening anything else in the machine. 
Hope this will work for solving both the mounting SSD/SDCard issue and the lock issue.